# How does Reflection work on a machine language level

Tags: c#, .net

I know reflection is done by "reading the metadata", but when it is compiled, how is it stored? Additionally, how much space gets taken up from the metadata? If a decompiler can regenerate my entire c# program from the metadata, is it storing almost as much metadata as written code?

Comment: See [Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language). Reflection happens far above the machine language level.

Comment: Relection does not go down to the machine language layer, rather it stays at the IL layer. You can determine the size of the metadata by looking at the  size of the PDB files.  Reflection doesn't require PDBs as it is able to look at  EXE only; however, there will be no symbols present.  Decompilers can regenerate C# programs using the IL layer; however, you can Obsfucate it so that nobody can really understand what's going on.  Metadata is not that large as it only exists in two forms PDB files and within the Header information of the Assembly, you can easily see it using the tool ILDASM.

Comment: @JohnPeters That would be better as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Ya, no doubt, but I'm tired of all the folks on these forums taking pot shots at answers.  I even had a guy downvote me yesterday on a very well written and researched question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the metadata if you open an assembly using **ildasm**.  You will see the list of classes, the attributes applied to the classes, referenced DLLs, the methods and signatures, ...  You would have to read the specifications of the .dll format for .NET executables to see exactly how much space it takes up and All of that is stored in the assembly in a more compact format than the assembly.

Then can then click on a method and you will see the code, compiled into **intermediate language**.  You will notice it is quite different from your source code.  A decompiler such as the free **ilspy** can't regenerate the C# program *exactly as your wrote it*.  The generated IL is not as low-level as say, x86 assembly, but it is high enough level that a decompiler can do a pretty good job though.  Enough that you can probably understand what the code was doing.

There are some other questions on stack overflow covering this topic.
[What are the `exact` differences between .NET dll and a normal dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259375/what-are-the-exact-differences-between-net-dll-and-a-normal-dll)

Also try some searches on the "Portable Executable" AKA PE format.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12585/The-NET-File-Format

I'm not so sure about how much actual storage size it is.  You would have to dig into the format to see.  Or try compiling some code and compare the code size to the executable size.

Answer (score 0):

> I know reflection is done by "reading the metadata", but when it is
>   compiled, how is it stored? Additionally, how much space gets taken up
>   from the metadata? If a decompiler can regenerate my entire c# program
>   from the metadata, is it storing almost as much metadata as written
>   code?

When your compiler compiles the code, it gets stored as IL code.  The mindset that your code is being literally saved is incorrect.  "Decompilers" or Reflectors aren't exactly perfect. They almost recreate what is initially compiled. If you look closely at the code you have written and the reflected code, they are not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET family of languages live in a runtime environment called the [Common Language Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (CLR).  When you compile a .NET language such as C# you are transforming the C# language into assemblies consisting of "intermediate Language" (IL) and it's associated metadata.  It is not until runtime that JIT compilation occurs and turns that IL into assembly language code.

A decompiler can generate code by reading the IL and using rules to generate C# or VB.NET or whatever supported .NET language you desire.  You are not getting the original code, rather a newly generated code based off whatever the IL contains and the mapping done by the decompiler.

As far as space you can look at the assemblies and PDB files to see their file size on disk using windows explorer.

Looking at how reflection is implemented is a futile exercise IMO.  The implementation details are not what is important.  Understanding that you can treat code as data is important.  There are various levels of accomplishing this task.  For a deeper understanding I recommend [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) or looking at other languages such as [clojure](http://clojure.org/lisp).