# Editing or creating a linked dll file

Tags: assembly, dll, exe, reverse-engineering

I have a simple exe file linked to a dll file, and it uses one function from it - `GetHour` (which simply returns the current time).
I want to change the dll file and insert my own function so that everytime the exe runs, a new file with some text in it will be created. Unforunately, I'm having trouble doing so.
I can't open the dll file with DotPeek, probably because it's not .NET (I don't fully understand what that means).
I tried writing a new dll file, with its own `GetHour` function, but failed due to the following error:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)
```

I don't really know how to deal with both my problems, and would really appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to change the DLL in-memory after it's loaded? Or just make a new DLL with its own implementation of the function?

Comment: This seems like a clear case of missing a [mcve] for a debugging problem.

Answer (score 0):

> .NET (I don't fully understand what that means).

On windows, you have two "types" of DLLs. You have "normal" DLLs, that contain native code (=Machine code) and .NET DLLs that contain the IL that was emitted by the C#-compiler (for example). [See here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259375/what-are-the-exact-differences-between-net-dll-and-a-normal-dll)

DLL files are [PE files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format), so they follow a special fileformat and if the DLL you created doesn't match, you will get this error. Editing a PE file in a hexeditor is quite difficult and errorprone.

There are tools like PE-Explorer, that will help you to fulfill your task, but they often require a good knowledge about the PE File format.